# How to create an efficient function to populate factor (t+1) in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am struggling to create an effective function in Python to populate a new column (i.e. factor (t+1)) with factor for the same id_policy but increase t by 1 each time. Can someone help, please?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The question depends on whether or not you are using any extra libraries like `pandas`, `numpy` or `scipy`.

If you wanted to do this with pure python here is a way you could do it

```py
factors = [0.332, 0.28, 0.225, 0.166]
factors_shifted = [0, 0, 0, 0] 

factors_shifted[:-1] = factors[1:]
```

if you wanted a generic function that could do this:

```py
def shift_factors(factors, n, fillvalue=0): 
    new_factors = [fillvalue] * len(factors)
    new_factors[:-n] = factors[n:] 
    return new_factors


new_factors = shift_factors([0.332, 0.28, 0.225, 0.116], 1)
```

If any of the above is unclear I suggest you read up on the following:
https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/

---

### update

given the conditioning on the `id_policy` the easiest way to achieve this would be using the `pandas` library

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        data = dict(
        id_policy=['PL0', 'PL1', 'PL1', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL0', 'PL1'],
        year=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
        factor=[0.33, 0.196, 0.135, 0.28, 0.225, 0.087, 0.166, 0.036]
    )
)

# ensure data is sorted by year
df = df.sort_values(by='year')

# this will shift all the values for each id policy by one to the left 
# NaNs are created when there are missing values, so we just fill these with 0
df['factor(t+1)'] = df.groupby('id_policy')['factor'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the data i pasted above is probably misleading, but I have updated now. It needs to be on the condition of the same id_policy as well, dont think the above will work.

Comment: Do you have access to additional libraries like `pandas`?

Comment: yes, i have, happy to install other libraries if necessary